# Toggle class using javascript between two

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, removeclass

classList to remove class using Javascript is not working, or is it because of any other error in code

Code: http://codepen.io/DPK_RAO/pen/VPXxoJ/

```
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#video1" id="link1" class="link1">Video 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#video2" id="link2" class="link2">Video 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="video1 active" id="video1">Link 1</div>
    <div class="video2" id="video2">Link 2</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video1, .video2{
   display:none;
}

.active{
  display:block;
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("link1").addEventListner("click", activeVideo1);

function activeVideo1(){
    document.getElementById("video2").classList.remove("active");
    var v1 = document.getElementById("video1");
    v1.className += "active";
}

document.getElementById("link2").addEventListner("click", activeVideo2);

function activeVideo2(){
    document.getElementById("video1").classList.remove("active");
    var v2 = document.getElementById("video2");
    v2.className += "active";
}
```

Comment: you have a typo in `addEventListener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run the script I get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).addEventListner is
>   not a function

So your script isn't even getting to the removeClass function and it stops in the event's listener part.

You write the function with a typo.
it's

> addEventList**e**ner

**Another note:**

Replace this:

```
v1.className += "active";
```

with:

```
v1.className += " active"; //added a blank
```

[**Updated codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNavNX)

Comment: Thank you, this works... spelling error and space required

Answer (score 1):

You've a typo in `addEventListner` should be `addEventListener` note the `e`:

```
addEventListener
____________^
```

Since you're using jQuery it could be just simple like the following example :

```js
$("#link1").on("click", function(){
    $("#video2").removeClass("active");
    $("#video1").addClass("active");
});

$("#link2").on("click", function(){
    $("#video1").removeClass("active");
    $("#video2").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.video1, .video2{
   display:none;
}

.active{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#video1" id="link1" class="link1">Video 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#video2" id="link2" class="link2">Video 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="video1 active" id="video1">Link 1</div>
<div class="video2" id="video2">Link 2</div>
```

**Solution using pure JS :**

```js
document.getElementById("link1").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("video2").classList.remove("active");
  document.getElementById("video1").classList.add("active");
});

document.getElementById("link2").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("video1").classList.remove("active");
  document.getElementById("video2").classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
.video1, .video2{
display:none;
}

.active{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#video1" id="link1" class="link1">Video 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#video2" id="link2" class="link2">Video 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="video1 active" id="video1">Link 1</div>
<div class="video2" id="video2">Link 2</div>
```

Comment: I want to use javascript. don't want to use <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ok i'll update the post adding the pure js solution, but you've to remove the `jQuery` tag from you question.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just add the class as in

```
var v2 = document.getElementById("video2");
v2.classList.add('active');
```

?

Comment: document.getElementById("link2").addEventListener("click", activeVideo2);
function activeVideo2(){
document.getElementById("video1").classList.remove("active");
document.getElementById("video2").classList.add("active");
}